# Images not appear in Release mode when compiling Xamarin UWP with .NET Native tool chain

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, toolchain, .net-native

Why images not appearing in Release mode when compiling Xamarin UWP with .NET Native tool chain? Images appear in Debug mode when compiling Xamarin UWP with .NET Native tool chain. When **unchecking** the Compile with .NET Native tool chain in Visual Studio 2017, the images appear in Release mode.

Comment: Two thoughts. If you turn on stopping for first chance exceptions, does anything appear out of place? I'm not super familiar with the Xamarin templates but you'll also want to ensure that your project includes a file like the one in the VS blank template app at Properties\Default.rd.xml. It'd be enough to add it to your project and mark it as "content".

Comment: Hi @MattWhilden! There is no exception being thrown when I compiled the app in Release mode. The Default.rd.xml file exist and here is the content of the file.    
    <pre><code><Directives xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2013/01/metadata">
  <Application>
    <!--
      An Assembly element with Name="*Application*" applies to all assemblies in
      the application package. The asterisks are not wildcards.
    -->
    <Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />
    <!-- Add your application specific runtime directives here. -->
  </Application>
</Directives>

Comment: Hmm. The only other thing I can think of off the top of my head is... maybe you're using dependency injection and don't have the proper registration? It works a bit strangely on .NET Native. See: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-dependency-injection/ If that doesn't turn anything up then I'll probably have to take a look more directly (I work at MS on the .NET team) firstInitialLastName@companyname.com

Comment: Hi @MattWhilden! To display the images, the code utilizing the **IValueConverter** _interface_ from [https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.IValueConverter/](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.IValueConverter/) `Assembly Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0` **packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.4.270** Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Can you send an ilcRepro file to the mail address I mentioned earlier? https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/ilcRepro.md

Comment: Hi @MattWhilden! I just sent you the **ilcRepro.zip** file (the _.NET Native Internal Compiler Errors_) to your work email address. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hi @MattWhilden! Are you able to figure it out? I am guessing the [Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/) is not compatible with the _.NET Native_ at this point of time, so I will just **uncheck** the Compile with .NET Native tool chain in Visual Studio 2017 when I compile the app in Release mode.